# Select count Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Estou querendo fazer um select com a função count e trazer todos os registros de uma tabela, mas ao apresentar a quantidade no textfield, ele exibe um resultado diferente. Vou colocar o código para vcs analisarem:

Erro apresentado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu codigo

```
public void TrazerValores(){

        try {
             String Tabela = "tb_produtos";
            String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+ Tabela ;


            //PEGANDO CONTAGEM DE VISITANTES
            PreparedStatement Stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

            ResultSet rs = Stmt.executeQuery();
            txtTotalProdutos.setText(rs.toString());



        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro em buscar a quantidade");
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Se a intenção é exibir o resultado da busca, não é transformando o `Resultset` em string, e sim, obtendo dele o valor da coluna:

```
public void TrazerValores(){

        try {
             String Tabela = "tb_produtos";
            String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+ Tabela ;


            //PEGANDO CONTAGEM DE VISITANTES
            PreparedStatement Stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

            ResultSet rs = Stmt.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            txtTotalProdutos.setText(rs.getString(1));



        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro em buscar a quantidade");
        }        
    }
```

Usei `getString(1)` levando em consideração de que o resultado será uma string, mas dependendo do tipo da coluna, você pode mudar isso. O `1` se refere ao indice da coluna que o valor será recuperado, pela sua query, aparentemente o retorno será uma unica coluna.

Leitura recomendada: [Processing SQL Statements with JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html)

Answer (score -1):

No caso seria:

```
txtTotalProdutos.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt(1)));
```

Pois o `count` retorna um valor do tipo `integer`.